# Mock "inner" object with Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Quite new to unittesting and mockito, I have a method to test which calls a method on a new object.
how can I mock the inner object?

```
methodToTest(input){
...
OtherObject oo = new OtherObject();
...
myresult = dosomething_with_input;
...
return myresult + oo.methodX();
}
```

can I mock oo to return "abc"?
I really do only want to test my code, but when I mock "methodToTest" to return "42abc", then I will not test my "dosomething_with_input"-code ...

Comment: Are you asking the question that is answered at https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/MockingObjectCreation or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: you are right, that answers my question, I expected that already. But I was hoping to find a way without the object-creating-methods, since I didnt want to change the code just to be able to unittest it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I consider the class that implements `methodToTest` is named `ClassToTest`

- Create a factory class for `OtherObject`
- Have the factory as a field of `ClassToTest`
- either

  - pass the factory as parameter of the constructor of `ClassToTest`
  - or initialize it when allocating the `ClassToTest` object and create a setter for the factory

your test class should look like

```
public class ClassToTestTest{
    @Test
    public void test(){
        // Given
        OtherObject mockOtherObject = mock(OtherObject.class);
        when(mockOtherObject.methodX()).thenReturn("methodXResult");
        OtherObjectFactory otherObjectFactory = mock(OtherObjectFactory.class);
        when(otherObjectFactory.newInstance()).thenReturn(mockOtherObject);
        ClassToTest classToTest = new ClassToTest(factory);

        // When
        classToTest.methodToTest(input);

        // Then
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do this. However, as an FYI, PowerMock does allow for mocking constructor calls. Again, I would suggest the above over PowerMock.

Comment: the only "problem" with this is that I have to refactor the code for the test to comply with this pattern